# WCF Compression with NetTcpBinding in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, compression, nettcpbinding

I finally managed to get compression working with NetTcpBinding in WCF in .net 4.0. But it seems quite nasty to me, so maybe someone else has a better idea.

Some general Information:

- I know this is working with .net 4.5 out of the box - but we are stuck to 4.0
- I found several examples with CustomBinding - but we want to stick with NetTcpBinding because of the binary enconding (it is simply faster than text enconding)
- We are doing all the configuration in code (except server address), so for the customer it is just plug and play and no chance to change anything - but made it also sometimes difficult to get an example working (most are provided in config files)

My first approach was implementing a message dispatcher on client and server side which does the compression:

http://dotnetlombardia.org/b/tonyexpo/archive/2011/03/09/compressione-in-wcf.aspx

But whenever I changed (or replaced) the original message by any means, the `AfterReceiveReply` on client side was never executed. 
Though in WCF traces I could see that the client received the message and did even send an ACK to the server which the server received! But the client went in timeout?!

Then I found the `MessageEncoderFactory` for compression by Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And applied the bug fix provided here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmetzgar/archive/2011/03/14/gzipmessageencoder-part-two.aspx

Finally I did inherit the NetTcpBinding and applied the new message encoder in the `CreateBindingElements` function:

```
    public class CompressedNetTcpBinding : NetTcpBinding
    {
        MyCompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement compressionEncoding;

        public CompressedNetTcpBinding()
            : base()
        {
            FieldInfo fi = typeof(NetTcpBinding).GetField("encoding", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement binaryEncoding = (BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement)fi.GetValue(this);
            compressionEncoding = new MyCompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement(binaryEncoding, CompressionAlgorithm.Deflate);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exchange <see cref="BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement"/> and use compressed encoding binding element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>binding elements with compressed message binding element</returns>
        public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
        {
            BindingElementCollection bec = base.CreateBindingElements();
            BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement enc = null;
            foreach (BindingElement be in bec)
            {
                if (be is BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement)
                {
                    enc = (BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement)be;
                    break;
                }
            }
            bec.Remove(enc);
            bec.Insert(2, compressionEncoding);

            return bec;
        }
    }
```

I did forward the ordinary BinaryMessageEncoder to the compression encoding, so when I change any settings of the NetTcpBinding, e.g. ReaderQuotas they are applied correctly.

I know the enconding member in NetTcpBinding is also used in the private function `IsBindingElementsMatch` but so far that did not cause any problems.

On my local machine, the (startup) performance penalty is insignificant (100ms - 250ms). But on LAN and WAN there is a significat performance increase (up to several seconds).

So what do you think:

- Is that a (the) way to go?
- Are there any better solutions?

Comment: i've been using standard protocols and use SharpZipLib to compress data myself and just that cutted down the size of my data by more than 90%. a DataTable of over 300 meg turn out less than 10 meg so transfer is much faster than i could ever imagine. using a lib like that the server compress and send the data as byte array so it transfer it like a stream so you can actiavte features to handle pause and resume transfer which is much more efficient than 1 shot transfer that if it fail at some point everything get canceled